# Correct all occurrences of misspelled word

Tags: vim, spell-checking

Is there a quick way to repeat a spelling correction?

For example, change every occurrence of `teh` to `the` after using `:set spell`, `z=` to correct the first occurrence?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After making the first correction with <kbd>z=</kbd>, e.g. *teh* to *the*, use `:spellrepall`, or shorter: `:spellr`.

Comment: Very nice, didn't know this before :)