# How to correct spelling in entire file?

Tags: vim

Spelling mistakes can be fixed by pointing the cursor on the misspelled word and pressing `z=` *(a list appears and you can select correct word)*. But this will fix the mistake only once *(on current word)*. This is not that much of us will want, most will be happy to do replacement in entire file. How can I do so?

#### Unsuccessful Attempt:

I got an idea of substitute that mistake with correct one *(i.e. `:%s/badspell/goodspell/g`)*. But the bad part of this is, it is painful. First I need to (atleast) correct a word, then store bad spelling and corrected spelling in **my buffer** *(brain)*, then write the command for  substitution *(chances are I will do mistake in writing bad spelling and good one.)*. Though its time taking too.

---

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047896/939986) on StackOverflow which says I can solve my problem with doing `:spellrepall` after the correction. The only problem is I don't want to all this typing. I want to automate this everytime there is a spelling correction.

<sub>*And don't suggest me about plugins.*</sub>

Comment: What about a simple mapping: `nnoremap <F8> :spellrepall<CR>`?

Comment: @romainl without mapping? Actually I'm flooded with mappings. How about any function? And also most of my function keys are mapped to operating system.

Comment: You want little typing, yet are against a mapping?! I think the `readMyBrainAndDoWhatIMean()` function hasn't been implemented yet in Vim.

Comment: I'm not telling you to read my brain. I want a function that does `:spellrepall` stuff and want call it on appropriate event.

Comment: Problem is, there is no `AcceptedSpellCorrection` event. You'd have to remap `z=`, and issue the `:spellrepall` after that. The difficulty is that `z=` may query for the correction. I've actually done that, but 1. it's a complex plugin, 2. not yet published, 3. you don't want plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If most of the time you're selecting the first fix from the query you can use a remap for `1z=` as such:

```
nnoremap 1z= 1z=:spellrepall<cr>
```

Although I would recommend binding `:spellrepall` to a seperate key as many people already suggested. I highly doubt you have run out of keybindings with all those `<leader>` and `<localleader>` combos. (something like `<leader>z` would be a perfect candidate for this)

I don't think this can go any easier without you loosening your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the spell on in .vimrc

```
set spell
```

or if u execute this on vim directly do in vim command mode.

```
:set spell
```

Once the spell is on, you need to know following command:

```
]s — move to the next mispelled word
[s — move to the previous mispelled word
zg — add a word to the dictionary
zug — undo the addition of a word to the dictionary
z= — view spelling suggestions for a mispelled word
```

Comment: if u want the fix for the entire file, and u want to fix it with the first suggestion thrown at by vim. in this case u can just record a vim-macro and run it like 1000 times.